# What causes Microsoft excel error "Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large Microsoft Excel file that is shared between users in my office. The file has a macro and a set of data validation. The file is used the last two weeks of every third month. The file worked perfectly before Christmas, however, we encountered errors in March.The following error appeared when the file was opened.
[image: Error]

After clicking yes, the following appeared.
[image]

The code for the macro is:

```
 Sub Update()

 'Declaring Variables.
  Dim Number_Rows As Long
  Dim Oppt As String
  Dim Array_Oppt() As String
  Dim Rows_Array As Integer

 'Stops screen refreshing to save time.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'removing any data validation and conditional formatting
  Sheet1.Activate
  Cells.Select
  Selection.Validation.Delete
  Selection.FormatConditions.Delete


 'Assigning value to array.
  Rows_Array = 0
  ReDim Preserve Array_Oppt(Rows_Array)


 'Moving "Other" rows to the end of the data
  Sheet1.Select
  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:= _
  "OTHER"

  Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count,       "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
 Selection.EntireRow.Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheet8.Select
 Sheet8.Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Sheet1.Select
 Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
 Selection.EntireRow.Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 Selection.AutoFilter

 Number_Rows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
 Sheet8.Select
 Selection.Cut
 Sheet1.Activate
 Range("A" & Number_Rows + 1).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 'Counting number of rows.
  Number_Rows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

  'Loop to check if oppt if unit or non unit deal. Checks if oppt is in array and adds oppt if not.
 'Calculates total revenue per opp.
  For i = 2 To Number_Rows

  Oppt = Range("I" & i)

'In array already.
If UBound(Filter(Array_Oppt, Oppt)) >= 0 Then

    'Non Unit deal in the array already. Deletes line and shifts row up as well as i up.
    If Range("W" & i) = "OTHER" Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Number_Rows = Number_Rows - 1
    i = i - 1

    'Unit deal in the array already.
    Else
    Range("J" & i) = ""
    End If

'Not in array so needs to be added.
Else
Range("J" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("I:I"), Oppt, Range("J:J"))

    If Range("W" & i) = "OTHER" Then

    Range(Cells(i, 19), Cells(i, 26)) = ""

    Else
    End If

'Redefines the size of the array factoring in new added row.
ReDim Preserve Array_Oppt(Rows_Array)
Array_Oppt(Rows_Array) = Oppt
Rows_Array = Rows_Array + 1
End If

Next


'Adds blank column for business manager.
 Columns("H:H").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Range("H1") = "Business Manager"


 'Updates the titles of the last columns in  file
  Range("AB1") = Date - 2
  Range("AC1") = Date - 1
  Range("AD1") = "Today"
  Range("AE1") = "Focus List"
  Range("AF1") = "% Chance"
  Range("AG1") = "Allocation Status"
  Range("AH1") = "New PO Date"
  Range("AI1") = Date - 3
  Range("AJ1") = Date - 4
  Range("AK1") = Date - 5
  Range("AL1") = Date - 6
  Range("AM1") = Date - 7
  Range("AN1") = Date - 8
  Range("AO1") = Date - 9
  Range("AP1") = Date - 10
  Range("AQ1") = "Partner Grouping"
  Range("AR1") = "VNX Models"
  Range("AS1") = "Commit + X"
  Range("AT1") = "Country"
  Range("AU1") = "Theater"


  'Moves to Sheet2 and copies Upside X column B to the end (column AV) for the purpose of VLookup. Then returns to Sheet1.
Sheet2.Activate
Sheet2.Columns("B:B").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheet2.Columns("AV:AV").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheet1.Activate


'Loop to add Linked status; and to complete VLookups from yesterday.
 For i = 2 To Number_Rows

'If to check linked status
If Range("L" & i) = "" Then
Range("M" & i) = "Not Linked"

Else
Range("M" & i) = "Linked"
End If


'Vlookups
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
'Vlookup to add business manager
Sheet1.Range("H" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("G" & i), Sheet3.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
'Vlookup to add comments from 2 days ago to column AB
Sheet1.Range("AB" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 20, False)
'Vlookup to add comments from yesterday to column AC
Sheet1.Range("AC" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 21, False)
'Vlookup to add data from Focus List column
Sheet1.Range("AE" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 22, False)
'Vlookup to add data from % Chance column
Sheet1.Range("AF" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 23, False)
'Vlookup to add data from Allocation Status column
Sheet1.Range("AG" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 24, False)
'Vlookup to add data from New PO Date column
Sheet1.Range("AH" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 25, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 3 days ago to column AI
Sheet1.Range("AI" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 19, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 4 days ago to column AJ
Sheet1.Range("AJ" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 26, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 5 days ago to column AK
Sheet1.Range("AK" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 27, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 6 days ago to column AL
Sheet1.Range("AL" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 28, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 7 days ago to column AM
Sheet1.Range("AM" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 29, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 8 days ago to column AN
Sheet1.Range("AN" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 30, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 9 days ago to column AO
Sheet1.Range("AO" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 31, False)
'Vlookup to add data from 10 days ago to column AP
Sheet1.Range("AP" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AR"), 32, False)
'Vlookup to add data to VNX Models column AR from VNX Models sheet 5 using Item Number column
Sheet1.Range("AR" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("W" & i), Sheet5.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
'Vlookup to add data to Upside X column B
Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("J" & i), Sheet2.Range("J:AV"), 39, False)
'Vlookup to add  Country to Country column AT based on Mapping Table sheet 4
Sheet1.Range("AT" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("G" & i), Sheet4.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
'Vlookup to add Theater to Theater column AU based on Mapping Table sheet 4
Sheet1.Range("AU" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("G" & i), Sheet4.Range("A:C"), 3, False)

If Err.Number = 0 Then
Else
End If


Next



 'Adding Formula for Commit + X Column AS for Conf Call Analysis file
  Range("AS2").Formula =     "=IF(C2=""Commit"",""Commit+X"",IF(B2=""X"",""Commit+X"",""""))"
  Range("AS2").Select
  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AS2:AS" & Number_Rows)




  '***********FORMATTING BELOW**************


 'Format Revenue column K - no decimal, 1,000 seperator.
  Columns("K:K").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

 'Format Forecast Close Date column P
  Columns("P:P").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"

 'Format Focus List column AE
  Columns("AE:AE").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"

 'Format % Chance column AF
  Columns("AF:AF").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"

 'Format cells with Dates as titles to dd-mm rather than long date
  Range("AB1:AC1").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "d-mmm"
  Range("AI1:AP1").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "d-mmm"


 'Add Data Validation to Allocation Status column
  Columns("AG:AG").Select
  With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=_Allocation"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With


 'Sorting by Description A-Z, Business Manager A-Z and Revenue $ Largest to    Smallest
  Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & Number_Rows _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H2:H" & Number_Rows _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("K2:K" & Number_Rows _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Sheet1.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AU" & Number_Rows)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


 'Hide Columns Quarter AA,Primary Partner OO, Reporting Product Type TT, Product Line VV, Opportunity Source Code QQ
 Columns("A:A").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 Columns("O:O").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 Columns("T:T").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 Columns("Q:Q").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 Columns("V:V").Select
 Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


 'Colours Today column AD yellow
  Columns("AD:AD").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With


 'Colours Allocation Status column AG blue
  Columns("AG:AG").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15773696
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With


  'Bold Headings in row 1
   Rows("1:1").Select
   Selection.Font.Bold = True


 'Adding Conditional Formatting Order Number column J, to highlight all duplicate values so that all oppts that have more than one row are red.
  Columns("J:J").Select
  Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False



 'Adding last updated date
  Sheet3.Range("J1") = Date


 'Allows screen to refresh at the end
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


 'Msgbox to advise when macro is complete.
  MsgBox ("File is now updated.")


  End Sub
```

I have figured out a number of work arounds, however, these slow down our productivity, and the error can comeback later on in the day. Can somebody tell me what is the likely cause of this problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your code which would cause the workbook corruption you're seeing.  You could try saving your file in a binary format (*.xlsb) and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Tim, I also don't think there's anything in the code. I have tried that myself and it seems to work, but why is the problem happening at all?

Comment: The error message is complaining about a named range, but there doesn't seem to be any code in your question which relates to named ranges.  Maybe Excel is having a problem with a too-long name, or some name format it doesn't like.  Difficult to say.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of the tab names causing an issue, I still don't see why there was no problem back in December and there is now though?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the file repair log?

Comment: Yes, it says "  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <logFileName>error062360_01.xml</logFileName> 
  <summary>Errors were detected in file 'Z:\Q1 2015\Con Call File\EOQ TRACKER - MARCH 20TH V2.xlsm'</summary> 
- <removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">
  <removedRecord>Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)</removedRecord> 
  </removedRecords>
  </recoveryLog>" Have you seen this before?

Comment: Have you been able to see that node in workbook.xml, before the repair?  I've had similar corruptions before without any Vba involved.  Sometimes excel just gets a little drunk while saving, sometimes it's a bad memory  or HDD sector, who knows.  If you can locate that node in the unzipped file, it may lend you some clarification, and may just be able to be removed manually.

Comment: I'm sorry to sound stupid, but how would I do that? I would like to point out that a new file was created daily from scratch, and the problem would appear most days. However, it did work perfectly before Christmas and nothing has changed int eh way the file was prepared?

Comment: Not stupid at all, we're all here to share and learn!  Under the surface, an .xlsx or .xlsm file is just a compressed folder with the extension changed from .zip to .xls(x/m).  If you changes the extension back to .zip, you can extract it like any other compressed folder.  That error message is complaining that one of the .xml files inside the compressed folder has something it doesn't like in it.

Comment: So make a copy of your original, and change the extension of the copy to .zip.  Windows will warn you, but it's OK.  Then, extract the contents, navigate to the xl folder, and open workbook.xml in notepad.  It's gonna look messy in there so hit ctrl+f and type in "named" and let's see if it finds a node with that word in it.  It will be enclosed like <nodeName>.  You can append your question with that section of the XML, and that will help us get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ok I did that but unfortunately it couldn't find anything called "named"? There is a section dealing with named ranges and defining them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75416/discussion-between-michael-chad-and-e-mcandrew).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid a lengthy comment section we continued in chat last night.  It wound up being quicker than anticipated.  He provided the definedName block below.

Although there are a number of things I saw that may/not have contributed, it looks most like a broken relationship in the shared views.  It is a shared workbook, on a network drive, and by the looks of it there are 6 different machines that have all stored some personal view data.  The syntax all looks OK, so without seeing all of the sheet*.xml files, its probably in one of the `<definedName>`, and `<customWorkbookViews>` / `<customSheetViews>` nodes which all relate based on GUID.  It's an easy thing to lose control over as those GUIDs are generated by excel at runtime.

Turning off "Filter Settings" in Review Tab>Share Workbook>Advanced Tab, under the "Include in personal view" heading will remove **all** of the `.wvu` named nodes from worksheet.xml, as well as `*View(s)` nodes from sheet*.xml, and keep them from re-appearing.  This will either fix the issue, or reduce the candidates to one user defined, and one system defined range.  Chances are that a recent save hiccup left some file parts without an update, and thus a broken relationship.

Drawback:  Only one view state can be saved, so you will see the last users format/filter changes upon opening the file.

Hope it really fixes it!  If not, we'll go another round.

[customSheetView Class MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.customsheetview.aspx)

[customWorkbookView Class MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.customworkbookview.aspx)

[UserBView MSDN (The strangely formatted Z_GUID part)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd949469(v=office.12).aspx)

The customSheetViewClass doc states that the GUID "**Shall correspond to a customWorkbookView**", where the customWorkbookView needs only to have a name  containing a globally unique GUID (redunant I know, but its in the docs). Failing the "Shall" requirement will result in the "Removed Records: Named Range from /xl/workbook.xml/ part (Workbook)" repair message.

```
'EOQ TRACKER - MARCH 20TH V2.xlsm\workbook.xls - definedNames
    <definedNames> 
        <definedName name="_Allocation">'6'!$A$2:$A$25</definedName> 
        <definedName name="_xlnm._FilterDatabase" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$AV</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_02EBD829_B457_4EED_8A23_48BD791D2A90_.wvu.FilterData" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A$1:$AU$5396</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_5038F31E_F522_4C27_8172_A37A2E0A913D_.wvu.FilterData" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$AV</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_6179D930_DC8C_44A7_9B7D_D78327247088_.wvu.Cols" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$A,'1'!$O:$O,'1'!$Q:$Q,'1'!$T:$T,'1'!$V:$V</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_6179D930_DC8C_44A7_9B7D_D78327247088_.wvu.FilterData" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A$1:$AU$5396</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_7736F281_6E25_4779_AF1F_AC145F2EB4E9_.wvu.FilterData" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A$1:$AU$5396</definedName>
        <definedName name="Z_A2BCDFEA_821A_444D_B1F8_3659E07AD9AC_.wvu.Cols" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$A,'1'!$O:$O,'1'!$Q:$Q,'1'!$T:$T,'1'!$V:$V</definedName>
        <definedName name="Z_A2BCDFEA_821A_444D_B1F8_3659E07AD9AC_.wvu.FilterData" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$AV</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_A2BCDFEA_821A_444D_B1F8_3659E07AD9AC_.wvu.Rows" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!:$1048576</definedName> 
        <definedName name="Z_AC1AB890_7D16_45DD_B4FB_13CB8F92D4C2_.wvu.Cols" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$A,'1'!$O:$O,'1'!$Q:$Q,'1'!$T:$T,'1'!$V:$V</definedName>
        <definedName name="Z_AC1AB890_7D16_45DD_B4FB_13CB8F92D4C2_.wvu.FilterData" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">'1'!$A:$AV</definedName> 
    </definedNames>
```